# Not getting filter data in Custom UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

I'm working on a project in swift 3 and I have a specific UIViewController where I have a UITableView and as to populate data on its cell, the data is get from the server and I assign it to an array of the type JSON. I wants to implement a custom UISearchBar as to filter these data. I have worked partially on code and its as bellow.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import SDWebImage


class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate {    

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!    
    var searchActive : Bool?
    var selectedCategoryList = [JSON?]()
    var filterSelectedCategoryList = [JSON?]()
    var lab :String?
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            passJson()

     self.searchBar.delegate = self
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

            func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    }
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            filterSelectedCategoryList = selectedCategoryList.filter { titles in
                return (titles?["healerName"].stringValue.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
            print("Array : ", filterSelectedCategoryList)
        }

     func passJson() {
            let path : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "JsonFile", ofType: "json") as String!

            let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!

            let readableJson = JSON(data: jsonData as! Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil)

            let json = readableJson

             print(json)

            let selectedItemArray = json["itemList"].arrayValue
            self.selectedCategoryList = selectedItemArray
            print("new prints",self.selectedCategoryList)
            tableView.reloadData()
            // print( "Count",selectedItemArray?.count as Any)


            self.count = self.selectedCategoryList.count
            print(self.count)


        }


        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if self.searchController.isActive && self.searchBar.text != ""{
                return filterSelectedCategoryList.count
            }else{
                return selectedCategoryList.count
            }

        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
            if count > 0 {
                if self.searchController.isActive && self.searchBar.text != ""{

                    cell.label.text = filterSelectedCategoryList[indexPath.row]?["healerName"].stringValue


                }else{
                    cell.label.text = selectedCategoryList[indexPath.row]?["healerName"].stringValue
                    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedCategoryList[indexPath.row]?["id"].stringValue
                    //cell.textLabel?.text=
                    self.lab = cell.textLabel?.text

                    cell.textLabel?.isHidden = true
                }


            }

            return cell
        }
```

Comment: i'm happy about your work, but why are you posting this?

Comment: Can you expand on what the actual issue is? It'll help answer the question

Comment: @Lu because my array is empty when filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code you are working with `UISearchBar` not with `UISearchController`, so you need to only compare `searchBar` text in methods `numberOfRowsInSection` and in `cellForRowAt`, don't compare `searchController.isActive` with it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.searchBar.text != ""{
        return filterSelectedCategoryList.count
    }else{
        return selectedCategoryList.count
    }        
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    if self.searchBar.text != ""{
        cell.label.text = filterSelectedCategoryList[indexPath.row]?["healerName"].stringValue

    }else{
        cell.label.text = selectedCategoryList[indexPath.row]?["healerName"].stringValue
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedCategoryList[indexPath.row]?["id"].stringValue
        //cell.textLabel?.text=
        self.lab = cell.textLabel?.text

        cell.textLabel?.isHidden = true
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: @danutha Welcome mate :)